# Erro ao gerar calendario em C

Tags: c

estava mexendo em um programa que gera um calendario para um mes
porem ele nao esta funcionando corretamente com anos bisextos pois 
em março de 1004 o primeiro dia começa quarta feira e o ultimo na sexta.

```
March 1004

Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
            1    2    3    4    5
  6    7    8    9   10   11   12
 13   14   15   16   17   18   19
 20   21   22   23   24   25   26
 27   28   29   30   31
```

ja o mes de fevereiro de 1004 esta gerando o calendario corretamente

```
February 1004

Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
            1    2    3    4    5
  6    7    8    9   10   11   12
 13   14   15   16   17   18   19
 20   21   22   23   24   25   26
 27   28   29
```

mas para o ano de 2004 ele nao gera o calendario corretamente, pois o primeiro dia de fevereiro de 2004 é domingo e o ultimo também é domingo..

```
February 2004

Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
                                1
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
  9   10   11   12   13   14   15
 16   17   18   19   20   21   22
 23   24   25   26   27   28   29
```

e o mes de março de 1987 o primeiro dia cai domingo e o ultimo na terça. Como resolver este erro?

```
Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
                                1
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
  9   10   11   12   13   14   15
 16   17   18   19   20   21   22
 23   24   25   26   27   28   29
 30   31
```

Segue o código:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

const char *months[]={
                      "\nJanuary","\nFebruary","\nMarch","\nApril","\nMay","\nJune","\nJuly","\nAugust","\nSeptember","\nOctober","\nNovember","\nDecember"
                     };

int month_days[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ,31 ,30, 31, 30, 31};

int first_day_year(int year)
{
    int first_day;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    x = (year - 1.)/4.0;
    y = (year - 1.)/100.;
    z = (year - 1.)/400.;

    first_day = (year + x - y + z) %7;

    return first_day;
}

int leapyear(int year)
{
    if(__isleap(year))
      month_days[2] = 29;
      return 1;
    else 
      month_days[1] = 28;
      return 0;
}

int calendar(int month, int year, int first_day)
{
    int i;

    printf("%s %d\n\n", months[month], year);
    printf("Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

    for(i = 0; i < month; i++)
    {
        first_day = ((first_day + month_days[month])%7);
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= 1 + first_day * 5; i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= month_days[month]; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d", i);

        if((i + first_day)%7 > 0)
            printf("   ");
        else
            printf("\n ");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int first_day;

    do{
        printf("Enter a month (1 - 12): ");
        scanf("%d", &month);
    } while (month < 1 || month > 12);

    do{
        printf("Enter a year (1000 - 3000): ");
        scanf("%d", &year);
    } while (year < 1000 || year > 3000);

    first_day = first_day_year(year);

    leapyear(year);

    calendar(month, year, first_day);

    printf("\n");

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: é linguagen C acontece que ele ficava invalidando tags entao coloquei c++

Comment: Já corrigi a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns erros que precisam de ser corrigidos:

- O array de meses com valor em falta

  O array `month_days` que está a utilizar:

  ```
  int month_days[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ,31 ,30, 31, 30, 31};
  ```

  Não joga com o que está a utilizar nas funções em relação às posições e por isso devia passar a ser:

  ```
  int month_days[] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ,31 ,30, 31, 30, 31};
  ```

  Em que foi adicionado a primeira posição como `0` para que o mês de posição 1 dê os dias de janeiro.
- A função `leapyear` tem os meses incorretos e falta de `{` `}` para o `if` e `else` pois esses tem duas instruções cada

  Pode corrigi-la assim:

  ```
  int leapyear(int year)
  {
       if((year% 4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || year%400 == 0){
            month_days[2] = 29; //agora [2] está certo devido ao primeiro ponto
            return 1;
       }

       //else é desnecessário basta fazer o retorno diretamente
       return 0;
  }
  ```
- Construção do primeiro dia para o mês incorreta

  Na função `calendar`, a definição do `first_day` não está a ser feita corretamente porque não está a utilizar a variável `i` do ciclo, assim como o começo deve ser outro considerando as alterações que propus acima.

  Ficaria então assim:

  ```
  int calendar(int month, int year, int first_day)
  {
      int i;

      printf("%s %d\n\n", months[month-1], year); //month-1 para imprimir o correto
      printf("Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

      for(i = 1; i < month; i++) //agora começa em 1
      {
          //+month_days[i] e não +month_days[month] que era o problema maior 
          first_day = ((first_day + month_days[i])%7); 
      }
      ...
  ```

  [Veja esta versão a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/MKiN7L)

**Edit**:

Para manter o array de dias dos meses sem o valor `0` inicial é necessário ajustar a função `calendar` e a `leap_year`:

```
int month_days[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ,31 ,30, 31, 30, 31}; //sem o 0
...

int leapyear(int year)
{
    if((year% 4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || year%400 == 0){
      month_days[1] = 29; //agora com mês posição 1, que é o segundo
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
...
int calendar(int month, int year, int first_day)
{
    int i;
    month--;//agora reduz o próprio month, pois em todos os locais que é
    //utilizado daqui para a frente tem de ter 1 a menos

    printf("%s %d\n\n", months[month], year); //sem -1 aqui, pois já foi reduzido acima
    printf("Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

    //volta ao i=0 que era o que tinha. month também tem agora -1 que veio de cima
    for(i = 0; i < month; i++) 
    {
        first_day = ((first_day + month_days[i])%7); 
    }
```

[Veja a versão sem `0` a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/DvRMI4)